# Split Dictionary Keys into List

Tags: python

Given a dictionary:

```
d = {'one two':2, 'three four':4, 'one three':0}
```

I would like to split the keys and create a list or set:

```
s = ('one','two','three','four')
```

I've tried:

```
s = set(kk for kk in k.split() for k in d.keys())
```

But this produces:

```
('four','three')
```

How can I get all of the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join all keys from the dictionary with a space, split the resultant string into a list possibly containing duplicates, then create a set from that list:

```
set(' '.join(d.keys()).split())
```

**Edit**
The following claim regarding complexity is wrong. Both are O(n) with the list comprehensions being slightly more efficient as no intermediate data structures are constructed. I've left the false claim here because there are good explanations in the comments.

This method is O(n). Your method, and those in other answers is O(n^2).

---

```
>>> d = {'one two':2, 'three four':4, 'one three':0}
>>> set(' '.join(d.keys()).split())
set(['four', 'three', 'two', 'one'])
```

Comment: "Your method, and those in other answers is O(n^2)" -- not true.

Comment: @SteveJessop  There are 2 for loops in those list comprehensions... isn't that O(n^2)?

Comment: The total number of things iterated over is the same either way: the number of words in the keys after splitting. So in both cases the complexity is the total length of all the keys (assuming we allow that sets work in `O(n)`, but that controversy affects all answers equally).

Comment: @mhawke it would be O(n^2) if *both* comprehensions looped over `d.keys()`.  Neither Marcin's nor Steve Jessop's do this.  One of the loops in each answer loops over the output of `<key>.split()`.  It's worth noting that neither of the other answer build an intermediary, eventually discarded, string that yours does.

Comment: @SteveJessop:  OK, you're right. I've double checked my claim and I take it back. I've edited the answer to reflect.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of set, you can use list comprehension to get all values after split:

```
s = [kk for k in d.keys() for kk in k.split()]
# ['three', 'four', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'three']
```

Or to get unique values, make it to set:

```
s = set([kk for k in d.keys() for kk in k.split()])
# {'four', 'one', 'three', 'two'}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I'm curious why the for-loops go in that order.

Comment: @Adam_G First for is outer loop, second for is inner loop. And you use `kk` values from the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using the functools.reduce in python 3.x

```
import functools
d = {'one two':2, 'three four':4, 'one three':0}

functools.reduce(or_,[set(k.split()) for k in d.keys()])
```

Output

```
{'four', 'one', 'three', 'two'}
```

for a tuple result you can do the following:

```
tuple(functools.reduce(or_,[set(k.split()) for k in d.keys()]))
```

Output

('four', 'one', 'three', 'two')

Unlike the previous answers this last edit adding the call to tuple returns a tuple as requested instead of a set.  As with the other solutions provided it is iterating through the dictionary keys, splitting the keys into elements and finally reducing the elements into one set.  Same level of complexity as the other solutions.

Comment: Any advantage to this, or just a different approach?

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, `or_` here is `operator.or_`.

Comment: And if you really like functional style, you'd want to go with `reduce(_or, map(compose(set, operator.methodcaller('split')), d))`. Except that tragically there is no standard `compose`.